# wpf/prism - Cannot update property value when working with integerupdown

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

As I was re-working an app's logic, I noticed that whenever I tried to work with `UIntegerUpDown` control from [this library](https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib), the property bonded to the control's `Value` property is never updated.
For example:

```xml
<cntrl:UIntegerUpDown Value="{Binding MinHeight}"/>
```

and

```cs
public uint MinHeight
{
    get => minHeight;

    // never called
    set => SetProperty(ref minHeight, value);
}
```

Comment: And what fails exactly ?

Comment: Prism can't update? How is this related to Prism?

Comment: @mm8 the `SetProperty` method is declared [in the prism packet](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/342689ba9a10e511418943438d0f5c57534ca623/src/Prism.Core/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs#L30-L38).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib/issues/36) of the NumericUpDownLib library, it appeared in v3.0.0.0

You can either roll back to v2.4.2.2 or propose a fix to the author.